# How does Cantor's diagonal argument not contradict the well-ordering theorem?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

If the the real numbers for instance have a well-ordering, can you not form a bijection from the reals to the natural numbers? Simply map the smallest of the reals to 0, and then iteratively map successors to each other.  What is it I'm missing here?

Comment: Why should it exhaust all reals?  Same as: any singleton is well-orderable, but you can't find a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If in a well-ordered set $X$ you call $0=\min X$ and $x+1:=\min\{y\in X\,:\, x<y\}$, then it isn't necessarily true that for all $x\in X\setminus\{0\}$ there is some $w\in X$ such that $x=w+1$. See for instance $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ endowed with the order $$(a,b)\leqslant (c,d)\Leftrightarrow a< c\lor(a=c\land b\le d)$$ The procedure you are sketching gives a bijection between *an initial segment* of your well-ordering $(\Bbb R,\le)$ and $\Bbb N$, but giving a global bijection is impossible.

Comment: @Gae. S. Ah, I see.  Since it is pretty much impossible to visualize a well-ordering of R, my intuition was defaulting to a countably infinite list.  Your ordering of NxN was a great counter-example that one can actually visualize.

Answer (score 0):

Such a map, from an infinite well ordered set to the
natural numbers, might not be defined for all members of the intended domain.
In fact it certainly will not if that domain has order type greater than omega.